# How can you do a mass unload of Assemblies from GAC by PublicKeyToken?

Tags: c#, assemblies, gac, gacutil

Is there anyway to unload all assemblies from the GAC that have a specific PublicKeyToken?

I am okay with the solution being command-line (gacutil.exe, etc) or via C#.

EDIT:

FYI, I can do this via Windows Explorer and going to the assembly folder and sort by public key and they select all the ones in question and right click and say uninstall.  If this is the only way then fine please confirm, otherwise alternatives that could be "automated" would be nice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the commandline and a little C# it's easy:

```
GacUtil /l
```

Lists all assemblies on CSV lines.
Filter this on the keytoken and feed the names to a `removelist.txt` for

```
GacUtil /ul removelist.txt
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I can do that, it still requires some manual effort, would love to know if there is anything better, this is still not easily to automate.

Comment: Maybe Powershell has tricks for this, other website. But I would call this reasonably automated.

Answer (score 1):

If you like `Powershell` you could use something like this:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe' /L | 
  where { $_ -match '^  ([\w\.]+,.*)$' } |
  foreach {
    if ($matches[1].contains("PublicKeyToken=d7e1d90e83a016b1")) {
      & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe' /u $matches[1]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GAC API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317540) to code your own tool. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/14/229649.aspx) is a managed version of the API.